# Pasar variables al bottomNavigationBar - Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hola queria saber como pasar los parámetros que obtengo de mi API a la parte del bottomNavigationBar.

Consulto mi API a través del parámetro que obtengo en la pantalla anterior:

```
Future<void> tomar_datos() async {
    registro.clear();
    //Esta slug la obtengo de mi pantalla anterior, según el registro en el que pulse me trae la información
    final slug = widget.slug!;
    var url =
        'http://url/api/local-sin-conexion/$slug?api_key=api;
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode > 199 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      final datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
      //print(datos);
      if (datos.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          registro.add(datos);
        });
      }
      //print(registro);
    } else {
      print('Ocurrió un error al hacer la consulta');
    }
  }
```

Me gustaría que lo que trae `datos` poder utilizarlo también en el `bottomNavigationBar`

Desde mi widget principal llamo a Navigation:

```
bottomNavigationBar: this.navInferior());
```

Y mi función navInferior:

```
Container navInferior() {
    return Container(
      height: 85.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[850]),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SvgPicture.network(
                          'http://url/images/svg/tender.svg',
                          width: 35.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "ITEM".toUpperCase(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 7.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 12.0,
            ),
            //Hay 5 opciones más

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: te recomiendo este articulo que escribí hace unos años: https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c

Comment: creas un navInferior para cada una de las pantallas?

Comment: Hola @JonathanPerez si en esta ocasión estas ventanas llevan una barra de navegación distinta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es pasar parámetros, la forma de pasar parámetros es declarando el tipo de variable que esperas recibir en tu función, entonces en la función debes asignar ese tipo de dato que esperamos recibir:

```
Container navInferior(List data) {
return Container(
  height: 85.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[850]),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        .....
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Ahora, supongo que lo que quieres hacer es reflejar esos datos dentro del `row`, entonces harías lo siguiente:

```
    Container navInferior(List data) {
    return Container(
      height: 85.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[850]),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
           Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SvgPicture.network(
                          data['url del icono'],
                          width: 35.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          data['nombre del item'].toUpperCase(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 7.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )), 
            SizedBox(
              width: 12.0,
            ),
            

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Y en el `bottomNavigationBar` tienes que agregarle la lista que deseas pasar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: this.navInferior(registro));
```

Espero y la respuesta te sirva

Comment: Pero es una pantalla donde ya consulto un registro único. Es decir en la barra de navegación solo necesito obtener la `id` del local que estoy visualizando, para de este modo a los botones del nav inferior añadirle ese parámetro, entonces ¿es necesario hacer un `for`?

Comment: Ahh, ok, entonces ya edito mi respuesta

Comment: Perdona si no lo explique bien en la pregunta

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, con ese ejemplo ya podrías hacer los demás items

Comment: Me devuelve est error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'` realizo un `print(data);` y lo que veo que me devuelve es `[{id: 65, user_id: 5, nombre: El chef del mar....`

Comment: Ah ya, en el data['nombre del item'] aumentale data[0]['nombre del item'], asi mismo del data['url del icono'] => data[0]['url del icono'] para poder obtener la posición del objeto, que en este caso es 0

Comment: Funciona bien, pero cada vez que entro en un local me sale de forma fugaz una pantalla roja como queriendo mostrar un error y de seguido sale bien, y en la consola me dice esto `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Comment: Claro, eso es porque está leyendo los datos en el initState, te recomiendo que muestres un Loading hasta que termine de leer los datos del initState

Comment: Seguro que es algo simple, pero como se hace eso?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137763/discussion-between-jonathan-perez-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarle parametro a la funcion de esta forma :

```
Container navInferior(List registro) {
return Container(
  height: 85.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[850]),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
    child: Row(
      children: [],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Y como accedo al objeto?

Comment: Depende como tengas definido el modelo, pero podria ser con registro['nombre'] o como lo tengas definido.